# In App Purchases .. Can I do this?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm making a music app. It's going to be free, but one of the in-app purchases is going to be 'Recording'. The user will have to buy the recording feature via IAP.
Is it possible for me to do this? The recording is going to be code, so im not sure if its possible.

**Update from comments:**

I'm not sure how to do it.  How would it be done?

Comment: Why are you guys down-voting? Comments would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is possible via inApp Purchase feature of the iOS from apple.

Here you just need to register the product/feature and you will get the product key from the apple developer account and use it in the application to unlock the given feature that is recording and you can do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it be possible? Simple answer to an even simpler question: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, how would it be done?

Comment: No one on SA will sit here and hold you hand while you implement in-app purchases. Start reading. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html